# Launching an exe at the end of a Visual Studio Setup Project of a c++ Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-installer

The only useful resource that describes how to launch an exe after the Visual Sutio Setup Project is finished is:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19560/Launching-Your-Application-After-Install-using-Vis.

However, my project is written in c++ and I don't see how I can integrate the `InstallerClass.cs` which is a c# class.

The reason I know it is not being automatically integrated into the install is because I get the error: "There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you could use `InstallShield` to realize the automatic operation of the program after installation.

The method of implementation is: In the OnEnd() function of the InstallScript script, call the executable program.

Note: The INSTALLDIR predefined variable stores the installation directory of the program.

You could refer to the following example.

```
//Run dispatcher after installation
strPath=INSTALLDIR+"dispatcher";
strName="Frs.exe";
FindFile(strPath,strName,strResult);
if(strResult!="") then
    strPath=strPath+"\\"+strName;
    LaunchAppAndWait(strPath,"",NOWAIT);
endif;
```

Comment: But that is the issue. In step 1 I cannot create an installer class because my project is written in c++ and not c#.

Comment: I'm sorry that I misunderstood what you mean. There seems to be no method. I suggest you use another deployment tool. I have revised the answer and hope it will help you.